# VC++ std::current_exception returns null in uncaught exception

Tags: c++, windows, exception

It seems that the default terminate handler in Windows does not print the ex.what() of the exception that caused it.

As a workaround I thought to implement a custom terminate handler to print the exception:

```
#include <iostream>

void term_func()
{
    std::cout << "term_func was called by terminate.(1)" << std::endl;
    std::exception_ptr eptr = std::current_exception();

    try
    {
        if(eptr)
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught exception \"" << e.what() << "\"\n";
    }

    std::cout << "term_func was called by terminate.(2)" << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::set_terminate(term_func);
    throw std::runtime_error("is windows broken?");
}
```

This works well in GCC and Clang++ (prints also the content of the exception), however in VC++ it only prints:

```
term_func was called by terminate.(1)
term_func was called by terminate.(2)
```

Now, are there any workarounds to this? Or to the initial problem?

Comment: Related [MSVC bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246253/msconnect-3133821-stdterminate-and-stdcurrent-exce.html).

Comment: If you want to display information about an exception, catch it.